# Pause streaming audio on Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I have this method to play an audio file with a button:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                    this,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                            + R.raw.inro));
            mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaplayer.pause();
                    } else {
                        mediaplayer.start();
                    }
                }
            });
```

What I'm trying to do is, when the audio is playing and the user clicks the button again, the audio will pause, but when he clicks it again the audio will resume.

### Updated

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_nav_back:
            WWHApplication.getMapActivityIntance().getVideoLocationDB();
            WWHApplication.getMapActivityIntance().initLocations();
            if (category == 'f') {
                if (WWHApplication.getFavoritesListActivityIntance() != null)
                    WWHApplication.getFavoritesListActivityIntance()
                            .loadListView();
            }
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_audio:
            final MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                            + R.raw.inro));     
                    if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaplayer.pause();
                    } else {
                        mediaplayer.start();
                    }

            break;
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: the pause method doesn't work, it does nothing when the user clicks the button while the audio is playing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to pause a audio inside on PreparedListener. IT doesn't work that way. Do the same inside a button click event,

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaplayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }
                }
    });
```

Prepared Listener gets called only when the source is ready and good to go with playing. It doesn't ensure the play and pause of your MediaPlayer.

Comment: I just updated the method I have on my question, but it doesn't work either. It's actually inside the onClick method

Comment: my friend, you are initializing your MediaPLayer each time in your button click. Remove this line 'final MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                            + R.raw.inro));  'from your switch case, and assign it globally. Or else each time when your button click gets called, your Mediaplayer initalizes and start t0 play from the beginning. that's the problem